# Критерий собирания купонов (для тестирования последовательностей)

Tags: статистика, теория-вероятностей, числовые-последовательности

Я читаю Дональда Кнута "Искусство программирования". Я не могу понять как применить хи-квадрат. Вот сам алгоритм [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Допусти у меня есть последовательность 1101221022120202001212201010201121. Далее я "собираю купоны", получаю вот такой массив [5,3,5,6,5,5,4]. Далее что делать с этим массивом я не понимаю. Как применить хи-квадрат и для чего эти вероятности (pr и pt)